# How to use preposition of software?

Tags: prepositions

The question is like

- > I do my report on/in Word.
- > I do xxx on/in Excel.

which is correct? use on or in.

Btw, I often use "I write my code on my computer." is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, I've heard 'in' mainly used for software that you're actively running, while other cases use 'on'.  There are some tricky nuances like 'look in Gmail' vs 'look on Wikipedia', suggesting that one looks 'in' a private web application but 'on' a public website.

Usage varies and is continuing to evolve.  Here are some examples:

> I write code and reports **on** the computer.  I do research **on** the internet; specifically, I search **on** Google and look **on** Wikipedia for new articles.
>
> I normally write the reports **in** Word and Excel.  I'm also learning to program **in** Python.  My problem is that today I'm **in** Windows but nothing happens when I click the start menu.  I can't even **get into** Control Panel. I'm looking **in** Gmail for my email with technical support.
>
> This kind of problem only seems to happen **on** Windows.  I have other problems **on** Linux or MacOS or Android, but not like this.  I'm running Windows **on** an old Toshiba laptop.

Comment: Would it be more correct to use "on" or "in" Microsoft Teams? I often get confused because we tend to use "on" when it comes to a drive or a platform like Facebook or SharePoint. Thanks!

Comment: Good question. I'll vote for "on" any platform where access is shared by multiple people, like you say, on Facebook or on SharePoint or on Microsoft Teams.